# Apply a label to the rowlist dropdown in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

jqgrid's rowlist option is an array of integers that it uses to construct a dropdown; the user makes a selection from the dropdown to specify how many rows to see on the page.  But there's no label next to the dropdown to tell the user what it's for.  Has anyone come up with a tidy solution to putting an explanatory label of text next to this dropdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jQuery("#<pager> .ui-pg-selbox").closest("td").before("<td dir='ltr'>No. Of Rows </td>");
```

Where `<pager>` is the id of the grid's pager.

Comment: Be aware that the .before() and .after() methods as used here are not idempotent, so if you use them in, say, a loadComplete event handler, you will need to write some first-time-only guard logic.

Answer (score 3):

Also the guard logic as mentioned above can be implemented as below:

```java
//declare a class level boolean variable as below and then 
//the following logic in the above code
var isPagesizelabelPopulated = false;

if (!isPagesizelabelPopulated)
    {
      $('.ui-pg-selbox').closest("td").before("<td dir='ltr'>Page size</td>");
      isPagesizelabelPopulated=true;
    }
```

Comment: This works, but adding the additional table cell to the pager table causes the pager content to bleed over the adjacent "View x of xxx" table cell to the right.  Has anyone found a way to resolve that issue?

Answer (score 1):

Inside the load complete method writing the below code worked for me which is in line with the above approach.

```
loadComplete: function () {
// some other code here
$('.ui-pg-selbox').closest("td").before("<td dir='ltr'>Page size</td>");
}
```

where `ui-pg-selbox` refers to to the rowlist drop down in the grid.

Comment: The problem with this method is that every time they perform some kind of action on the grid, it adds another "Page size".

Answer (score 0):

As suggested above you can select the table or div which contains the select input with class ui-pg-selbox and then set the label. You can do it this in the jQuery(window).load() event but not in the jQuery(document).ready();  event bcz those elements may not be available in the ready() state.

Answer (score 0):

solution for : "The problem with this method is that every time they perform some kind of action on the grid, it adds another 'Page size'"

Add a class to the Page size, like
Page size

Add an If/Else case in the loadComplete with following statement :
if ($(".rowListLabel")[0]) { do the label creation } else { do nothing }